# Rails: Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I am running the command

```
bundle install
```

in a project folder. In some project folders it will produce an error and in other projects folders it will not produce an error. The error is:

> Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems

I know this can be fixed by following the recommended advice:

> ```
> bundle install --path vendor/bundle
> ```

My question is why is the behavior inconsistent?

Comment: Also I notice that Travis CI run exactly the command `bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3` but it actually implicitly installs in `vendor/bundle` as per https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/#Default-Test-Script

Comment: just removing Gemfile.lock solved my problem

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65800841/6889226) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51126403/6889226) is also applicable to OP's problem.

Answer (score 36):

In my case, I solved doing just what the error message suggests:

```
Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

      bundle install --path vendor/bundle

  to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/
```

So, instead of:

```
bundle install
```

I ran:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

That was the solution for [this guy](https://mycyberuniverse.com/web/how-fix-user-account-isnt-allowed-install-system-rubygems.html).

The downside of that solution is that it creates a `vendor` folder inside the current folder, which can be added to `.gitignore` if it is to distribute the application through Git.

Comment: In the case of a [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) static website, also add `vendor` to the `exclude` setting in `_config.yml`. For more information, see: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/troubleshooting/#configuration-problems

Comment: Instead of adding `vendor` to `.gitignore`, you can add it to `.git/info/exclude`. The file `.git/info/exclude` is not tracked.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar experience. I would have simply ran the code below to fix it temporarily

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

The downside to this is that it does not solve the issue permanently, as the issue will re-surface when you start out with other Ruby on Rails Applications.

**I tried this solution, but it did not work for me:**

Display a list of all your local gems for the bundler gem

```
gem list bundler
```

**N/B:** The command above is for rbenv version manager, the one for rvm might be different

This will display the versions of the bundler gem installed locally

```
bundler (2.0.2, default: 1.17.3, 1.10.6)
```

And then ran the code below below to uninstall version `1.10.6`

```
gem uninstall bundler
```

Afterwhich I ran the code below to rehash rbenv

```
rbenv rehash
```

However, this did not solve the issue.

**Here's how I solved it;**

The issue was that I mistakenly ran a `bundle install` operation with administrative rights, that is:

```
sudo bundle install
```

which made the owner of the `~/.rbenv` OR `~/.rvm` directory to become `root`

To solve the issue I ran the code below to change the ownership of the files and directories.

For **rbenv** users:

```
sudo chown -R $USER  ~/.rbenv
```

And for **RVM** users

```
sudo chown -R $USER  ~/.rvm
```

That's it.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Didn't worked but this helped me remember that I have `rvm`. So I tried using the most recent `rvm` version then boom. It worked!

Answer (score 15):

Usually if you're using RVM, rbenv or chruby to install Ruby, all the gems will be installed in your home folder under `~/.rbenv/ruby-version/...`

If you're using your system Ruby though (the one that is installed by default) the gems are installed alongside it in a location that you don't have access to without `sudo`.

My guess would be that your version manager defaults to the system Ruby but some of your projects have a .ruby-version file in them that tells it to use a different version of Ruby which you have access to.

Comment: hats off to you man!

Answer (score 7):

### Good rbenv fix

- Avoids sudo
- Avoids install to vendor/bundle

**The problem, at least for me, was that bundler itself wasn't installed in my rbenv ruby version.  *Even though bundler existed and seemed usable... except the permissions error.***

One of the things that clued me in was that at the actual command line itself I could install gems ok and not get the error message.  I did this for a while as a work-around until I decided to fix the problem permanently as shown below:

To fix it I did:

```
rbenv local 2.5.0 # Make sure I'm using a local version that exists
gem list | grep bundler # Note no output! Need to fix that!
gem install bundler
rbenv rehash
bundle (within my project that has a Gem file)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using RVM:**

You have to install `rvm` for your single user (**standard user / non root user**), in your `$HOME` directory (It's not installed if you don't have `/home/youruser/.rvm` directory.

As is specified [on rvm site](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#installation) under "Single-User Install Location: ~/.rvm/" section, to install `rvm` for single user run:

```
cd
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --ignore-dotfiles
```

Now, `rvm` should be installed. As in further prompt, refresh `rvm` (with your username provided):

```
source /home/---YOURUSERNAME---/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

To prevent prompts for installing sudo-need packages, run:

```
rvm autolibs disable
```

You can install Ruby for your user only, in version 2.5 (or any other, listed in `rvm list known`)

```
rvm install 2.5
```

**Explanation:**

You probably try to install rvm using `sudo` and maybe with [this package for ubuntu](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm) but you don't have sudo permissions.

This prompt is telling you that you can't bundle gems globally for the whole system,
which may be good for your private home machine but not for your corporate user(machine), which is often administered by someone else.

If rvm will be installed in your `$HOME` gems will be bundled there, like usual.

Behavior may be inconsistent because other users have `rvm` installed in their `$HOME` directory

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows 10 store, you may need to `sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade` & `sudo apt install gnupg2` before all other commands

Answer (score 3):

- Open your **bashrc** or **zshrc** file.
- Add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`at the end of the file and save it.
- Run source ~/.zshrc or source ~/.bashrc

You can also close and open the terminal.
bundle install and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had an existing `$BUNDLE_PATH` without enough permissions to the bundler user to write in.

```
Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently faced the same issue. I use `rvm`

`sudo chown -R $USER  ~/.rvm` helped for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `rbenv`, all you need to do is provide a `.ruby-version` file.