# Error when running the command bundler install

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundle

I'm new to bundle and ruby and I've just installed bundle 2.2.17 and ruby 3.0.1. When I ran the command `bundle install`, I got the following error. After tracing back the error, I was still not able to understand the error and identify the reason for having this error. If someone could instruct me about how I can get started with solving this, that would be very helpful. Below is the output message I got after running the command:

```
Resolving dependencies....
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using zeitwerk 2.4.2
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using bundler 2.2.17
Using colorator 1.1.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.11.1
Using execjs 2.8.1
Following files may not be writable, so sudo is needed:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/build_info
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/cache
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/doc
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/specifications
Using faraday-excon 1.1.0
Using faraday-net_http 1.0.1
Using multipart-post 2.1.1
Using forwardable-extended 2.6.0
Using gemoji 3.0.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.11.0
Using rexml 3.2.5
Using mercenary 0.3.6
Using rouge 3.26.0
Using safe_yaml 1.0.5
Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7
Using liquid 4.0.3
Using jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
Using rubyzip 2.3.0
Using jekyll-swiss 1.0.0
Using unicode-display_width 1.7.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.9
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using pathutil 0.16.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using kramdown 2.3.1
Using terminal-table 1.8.0
Using activesupport 6.0.3.7
Using ruby-enum 0.9.0
Using jekyll-coffeescript 1.1.1
Using kramdown-parser-gfm 1.1.0
Fetching ffi 1.15.0
Fetching unf_ext 0.0.7.7
Fetching racc 1.5.2
Using faraday-net_http_persistent 1.1.0
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.4
Fetching commonmarker 0.17.13
Using faraday 1.4.1
Using sawyer 0.8.2
Using octokit 4.21.0
Using jekyll-gist 1.5.0


Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
  You can cancel this installation and run:

      bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle'
      bundle install

  to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
  and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.

  Password: 
Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
Installing commonmarker 0.17.13 with native extensions
Installing racc 1.5.2 with native extensions
Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.7 with native extensions
Installing ffi 1.15.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/private/var/folders/v5/f0xx2vq95039ds03fshsy_980000gn/T/bundler20210520-20868-8wnof7commonmarker-0.17.13/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13/ext/commonmarker
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20210520-20868-8zcp2h.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
/private/var/folders/v5/f0xx2vq95039ds03fshsy_980000gn/T/bundler20210520-20868-8wnof7commonmarker-0.17.13/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13/ext/commonmarker
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/private/var/folders/v5/f0xx2vq95039ds03fshsy_980000gn/T/bundler20210520-20868-8wnof7commonmarker-0.17.13/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13/ext/commonmarker
make "DESTDIR="
make: *** No rule to make target
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/universal-darwin19/ruby/config.h',
needed by `arena.o'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/var/folders/v5/f0xx2vq95039ds03fshsy_980000gn/T/bundler20210520-20868-8wnof7commonmarker-0.17.13/gems/commonmarker-0.17.13
for inspection.
Results logged to
/var/folders/v5/f0xx2vq95039ds03fshsy_980000gn/T/bundler20210520-20868-8wnof7commonmarker-0.17.13/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/commonmarker-0.17.13/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing commonmarker (0.17.13), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install commonmarker -v '0.17.13' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  github-pages was resolved to 214, which depends on
    jekyll-commonmark-ghpages was resolved to 0.1.6, which depends on
      jekyll-commonmark was resolved to 1.3.1, which depends on
        commonmarker


Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/private/var/folders/v5/f0xx2vq95039ds03fshsy_980000gn/T/bundler20210520-20868-vi8pkcunf_ext-0.0.7.7/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.7/ext/unf_ext
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20210520-20868-i4vcac.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lstdc++... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-static-libstdc++
        --without-static-libstdc++
        --with-stdc++lib
        --without-stdc++lib
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in
`try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in
`block in try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in
`mktmpdir'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in
`try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in
`try_link'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:789:in
`try_func'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1016:in
`block in have_library'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in
`block in checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in
`block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in
`open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in
`block in postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in
`open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in
`postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in
`checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1011:in
`have_library'
        from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/var/folders/v5/f0xx2vq95039ds03fshsy_980000gn/T/bundler20210520-20868-vi8pkcunf_ext-0.0.7.7/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.7/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/var/folders/v5/f0xx2vq95039ds03fshsy_980000gn/T/bundler20210520-20868-vi8pkcunf_ext-0.0.7.7/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.7
for inspection.
Results logged to
/var/folders/v5/f0xx2vq95039ds03fshsy_980000gn/T/bundler20210520-20868-vi8pkcunf_ext-0.0.7.7/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/unf_ext-0.0.7.7/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds
before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  github-pages was resolved to 214, which depends on
    github-pages-health-check was resolved to 1.17.0, which depends on
      dnsruby was resolved to 1.61.5, which depends on
        simpleidn was resolved to 0.2.1, which depends on
          unf was resolved to 0.1.4, which depends on
            unf_ext
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with bundler using rails (mac user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66460196/problem-with-bundler-using-rails-mac-user)

Answer (score 0):

This error might be related to:
[Rails: Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843948/rails-your-user-account-isnt-allowed-to-install-to-the-system-rubygems)

after that try to execute
gem install commonmarker -v '0.17.13' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
to check if this gem will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a duplicate of: [Problem with bundler using rails (mac user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66460196/problem-with-bundler-using-rails-mac-user)

You need to install updated xcode. Go to your terminal and run: xcode-select --install